# Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory when I try to create a new Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot

I am quite a newbie in developing web projects using Spring. I am trying to create a new Spring Boot project but I am not able to run the application that I am creating. 
I have tried all the suggested answered related to this topic, but without any luck. 
This is my error:

```
 Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
   Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/spi/LifeCycle
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:59)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:50)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:179)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.spi.LifeCycle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/core/spi/LifeCycle
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:59)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:50)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:179)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.spi.LifeCycle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: logback jar is missing from classpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following library to `pom.xml`

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Try this also :

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

and do a `maven update`

Comment: Nope, tried this, but the same error is displayed :(

Comment: I added the dependency and ran mvn dependency:purge-local-repository.
After that, the project was running, but still with some issue related to the server port. I added in the _application.properties_ file a new port and the project is running smoothly. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately this is the message that I receive when I try to upvote: _Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score._